# How to save image in a folder in asp.net using ajax or jquery

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net

jquery code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnsubmit").click(function () {

            var name = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtname").val();
            var course = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtcourse").val();
            var qualififcation = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtqualification").val();
            var company = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtcomp").val();
            var salary = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtsal").val();
            var role = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtrole").val();
            var description = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtdesc").val();
            var status = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddstatus").val();
            var image = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload1").val();

            var url = "ajaxhandler.aspx?taskname=insertstudent";
            $.post(url,
                {
                    name: name, course: course, qualififcation: qualififcation, company: company, salary: salary,
                    role: role, description: description, status: status, image: image
                },
                function (data, status) {
                    if (status == "success") {
                        alert("student inserted");

                    }
                }
            )
        });
    });
```

ajaxhandler page code

```
  int  image = Convert.ToInt32( Request.Form["image"]);

        int a = BLL.studentbll.insertstudent(name,course,qualification,company,salary,role,description, status);

        if (image>0 )
        {
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(image.FileName);
            image.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images\\" + Convert.ToString(a) + ".jpg"));
        }
```

seems error while storing image
image.filename is inaccessible
 How to save image in a folder in asp.net using ajax or jquery

Comment: here ajax doesn't  pass the image files so you could retireve the file by normally

Comment: var image = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload1").val(); is this right way to pass the imge

Answer (score 1):

Here ajax doesn't pass the image files so you could retrieve the file by normally in ajax handler

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
```

Here is the reference site link:

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-save-images-into-folder-and.html